# CGPath (AddCurveToPoint) - the difference between the first control point's x and y and the second

Tags: objective-c, quartz-graphics, cgpath

I'm pretty new to Xcode so I've decided to get used to Quartz drawing, although I'm slowly getting used to it, I'm having trouble drawing bezier paths.

In particular, from my Illustrator design, I want to draw a shape (the Spade logo from a pack of playing cards) although the x and y points are OK, I think I'm mixing up which point is the first control point and which is the second.

I always imagined it as, if you imagine a desk and rotate the outside of the shape along the top of it (so the shape is always on the desk as oppose to below it) the first control point is on the left and the second is on the right.

What is the case?

Thanks in advance, Adam.

[image: Here is a picture describing what I mean]

And here is my code:

```
CGMutablePathRef spadePath = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(spadePath, NULL, 17.0f, 0.0f);

CGPathAddCurveToPoint(spadePath, NULL, 17.0f, 7.3f, 17.0f, 7.318f, 34.0f, 25.475f);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(spadePath, NULL, 34.0f, 14.754f, 34.0f, 36.197f, 20.838f, 35.029f);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(spadePath, NULL, 24.679f, 38.425f, 20.838f, 41.03f, 17.0f, 39.2f);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(spadePath, NULL, 2.846f, 39.2f, 31.156f, 39.2f, 13.163f, 35.029f);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(spadePath, NULL, 13.163f, 41.03f, 9.323f, 38.425f, 0.0f, 25.475f);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(spadePath, NULL, 0.0f, 36.197f, 0.0f, 14.754f, 17.0f, 0.0f);

CGPathCloseSubpath(spadePath);
```

Comment: I a,ways just figure this just out by trial and error. But there is an awesome program where you could draw shapes and it will output CG code. http://www.paintcodeapp.com/

Comment: Looks good! But not for $100! It obviously follows logic though?

Answer (score 4):

Ive just figured out the answer to my own question, when drawing the curve you are telling it the essential coordinates for that one section.

So when parsing the x and y coordinates for control point 1, you are giving the control point coordinates of the essential control point to the beginning point and the same for the last point, as well as the location for the last point.

For example,

[image: Sector drawing with control points]

Answer (score 2):

You've transcribed some of your coordinates incorrectly.  For example, here's your first curve:

```
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(spadePath, NULL, 17.0f, 7.3f, 17.0f, 7.318f, 34.0f, 25.475f);
```

But according to your diagram, it should be this:

```
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(spadePath, NULL, 17.0f, 7.318f, 30.0f, 14.754f, 34.0f, 25.475f);
```

However, in the Illustrator diagram, it also looks like the control points attached to point 2 are labeled with the wrong X coordinate.  They're labeled 30 but should probably be labeled 34.  I didn't check all of the labels.